# PostgreSQL csv import not working for only integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have the following problem using PostgreSQL 14
On Windows 10 with latest updates.

I need to insert values into the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE StateList (
    ID int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    State_Number int NOT NULL,
    ElectionGroup_ID INT NOT NULL,
    Election_Number int NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (State_Number, ElectionGroup_ID, Election_Number),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

I want to do the following command:

```
COPY StateList(Election_Number, State_Number, ElectionGroup_ID )
FROM '...\csvFileStateLists19.csv'
WITH (
    FORMAT CSV,
    DELIMITER ','
    );
```

the "csvFileStateLists19" being

```
"19","9","4"
"19","5","238"
"19","5","21"
"19","15","1"
"19","5","10"
```

It worked fine for another table that used strings and integer.
But here I always get:

> ERROR: FEHLER:  ungültige Eingabesyntax für Typ integer: »19«
> CONTEXT:  COPY statelist, Zeile 1, Spalte election_number: »19«
>
> SQL state: 22P02

Which is usually the sign that the number is an empty string or really not a number. but its not! It's a 19, why doesn't it work?

I generated the file in java,
its utf8 encoded,
database is "German_Germany.1252"

show client_encoding; => UNICODE
show server_encoding; => UTF8
SELECT pg_encoding_to_char(encoding) FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'database1'; => UTF8

select pg_encoding_to_char(encoding), datcollate, datctype from pg_database where datname = 'database1';

Returns
"UTF8"  "German_Germany.1252"   "German_Germany.1252"

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where is the CSV file coming from? What is its encoding? What is the encoding for the database? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: I generated the file in java, its utf8 encoded, database is... default? i think utf8

Comment: In `psql` do `show lc_ctype ;`.

Comment: In `psql` what does `\encoding` return?

Comment: UTF8 
 when i do SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;

Comment: Yes but in `psql` what does `\encoding` or if you prefer `show client_encoding;` return? Also the output of  `\l <database_name>? Add as update to your question along with `server_encoding` so folks don't have to dig through the comments for this information.

Comment: did it, sorry for not including all information immediatly

Comment: `FROM '...\csvFileStateLists19.csv'` The three dots, it that some kind of platform-convention? [ and the backslash ???]

Comment: Please when I ask for specific piece of information provide it. So what is returned when you do `\l <database_name>`? What OS and version is the Postgres on?

Comment: i have no idea what that whole \l thing is...

"FROM '...\csvFileStateLists19.csv'" means its local somewhere in my pc, that is not the focus here! its some file i generated.

Comment: Are you using `psql` to connect?

Comment: pgAdmin is what i use

Comment: Then: `select pg_encoding_to_char(encoding), datcollate, datctype from pg_database where datname = 'database1';`.  Also what OS and version is Postgres server on?

Comment: I added it to my answer already, windows 10 latest update.

"UTF8" "German_Germany.1252" "German_Germany.1252" is the result

Comment: Oops I missed that. Since you are `pgAdmin` have you tried the [Import/Export Dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.0/import_export_data.html)? It uses `COPY` under the hood.

Comment: FEHLER:  ungültige Eingabesyntax für Typ integer: »19«
KONTEXT:  COPY statelist, Zeile 1, Spalte id: »19«

Still the same mistake... 19 IS an Integer, why in the world doesn't it recognize that?

Comment: Can you look at the file with `od` or some other binary viewer?  Might there be unprintable characters getting in the way?

Comment: ï»¿"19","9","4" ! You might be onto something! strange letters appear in front of the 19

Comment: thank you, jjanes! It gave me the clue I was missing. I had to adjust another file with "FileOutputStream  csvFileCandidates19 = new FileOutputStream(Main.csvResultFilePath + "csvFileCandidates19.csv");
   FileOutputStream  csvFileStateLists19 = new FileOutputStream(Main.csvResultFilePath + "csvFileStateLists19.csv");
   csvFileCandidates19.write(0xef);
   csvFileCandidates19.write(0xbb);
   csvFileCandidates19.write(0xbf);" to be UTF8 and that wasnt needed here. so i deleted it and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Well, with your input, I get the same error message - just in English, not German - I did it in Vertica, Stonebraker's successor of PosgreSQL, whose CSV parser works very much the same:

```
COPY statelist FROM LOCAL 'st.csv'  DELIMITER ',' EXCEPTIONS 'st.log';
-- error messages in "st.log"
-- COPY: Input record 1 has been rejected (Invalid integer format '"19"' for column 1 (State_Number)).
-- COPY: Input record 2 has been rejected (Invalid integer format '"19"' for column 1 (State_Number)).
-- COPY: Input record 3 has been rejected (Invalid integer format '"19"' for column 1 (State_Number)).
-- COPY: Input record 4 has been rejected (Invalid integer format '"19"' for column 1 (State_Number)).
-- COPY: Input record 5 has been rejected (Invalid integer format '"19"' for column 1 (State_Number)).
```

Well, that's no wonder really. `"9"` is a string literal, not an INTEGER literal. It's a VARCHAR(1) consisting of the numeric letter "9", not an INTEGER.

Try adding the `ENCLOSED BY '"'`  clause. It worked for me:

```
COPY statelist FROM LOCAL 'st.csv'  DELIMITER ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' EXCEPTIONS 'st.log';
-- out  Rows Loaded 
-- out -------------
-- out            5

SELECT * FROM statelist;
-- out  State_Number | ElectionGroup_ID | Election_Number 
-- out --------------+------------------+-----------------
-- out            19 |                5 |              10
-- out            19 |                5 |              21
-- out            19 |                5 |             238
-- out            19 |                9 |               4
-- out            19 |               15 |               1
```

Comment: And you would be wrong, see my 'answer'. This is why it is important to use the program(Postgres) the issue is arising in.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer just proof that double quoted numeric values in a CSV are not the problem:

```
cat csv_test.csv 
"19","9"
"19","5"
"19","5"
"19","15"
"19","5"


test(5432)=# \d csv_test 
              Table "public.csv_test"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 col1   | integer |           |          | 
 col2   | integer |           |          | 

select * from csv_test;
 col1 | col2 
------+------
(0 rows)

\copy csv_test from 'csv_test.csv' with  csv;
COPY 5

select * from csv_test;
 col1 | col2 
------+------
   19 |    9
   19 |    5
   19 |    5
   19 |   15
   19 |    5
```

So now maybe we can get on with answers that solve the issue.